# get indices of strings in a list that are present in another list

Tags: python

```
l = ['foo','bar','baz']

l2 = ['xbary', 'uobazay', 'zzzfooaa']
```

How can I get the position of the strings in `l` that appear in `l2`?

```
p = [1,2,0] #because bar is in index 1 of l, baz in index 2 and foo in index 0
```

Comment: Will there ever be a word in l2 with more than one word from l?

Comment: @JohnColeman `[2,0,1]` would be if `l = ['baz','foo','bar']`. Yes every string in `l` appears in `l2`

Comment: @RichardKYu, no

Answer (score 1):

You could use a double for-loop where the inner loop `enumerate` over `l` to get the indices:

```
out = [i for item2 in l2 for i, item1 in enumerate(l) if item1 in item2]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
res = [i for elem in l2 for i in range(len(l)) if l[i] in elem]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0]
```